# Force Python to update command history file from command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-history

I use Python without a GUI/IDE by issuing `Python` from the Bash command line.  I use it within a Cygwin environment, which behaves like a Linux system in many respects.

The file used for the history of commands issued at the Python command line is stored in `~/.python_history`.  I can easily scoot in and yank content for manipulation using vim's [Buffer Explorer](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42).  It's also easy to yank manipulated content into the system clipboard for pasting at the Python command line.  (For more tactical revisions of commands, on the other hand, I just use readline to vim previous commands and a single-line basis.)

I have found that `~/.python_history` doesn't update after each command.  I'm not sure how often it is updated, but it's clear that exiting Python causes it to update.  Putting into the background with Ctrl+Z does not.

**(Is there a quick and convenient way from the Python command line to force an update to `~/.python_history`?**

Since my original posting of this question, I've had occasion to figure out Linux (Ubuntu) as a VirtualBox virtual machine.  However, it seems very excessive to fire up an entire guest operating system just to be able to access the command history as a palette as opposed to one line at a time using the Up-Arrow key (or equivalently, `k` if one's command line editor is set to Vim).  I'd even be happy with a Python counterpart to Bash's "fix command" ([fc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fc_(Unix))) command, even though I would have to erase all the lines that I don't want to execute.

---

**Various things tried**

As per the responses, I tried importing `readline.write_history_file`, but it isn't recognized, even though `readline` itself is:

```
$python
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 20 2021, 11:41:59) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

# Show modules
>>> import sys
>>> modulenames = set(sys.modules) & set(globals())
>>> allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames]
>>> print(allmodules)
[<module 'sys' (built-in)>]

# Fail to import readline.write_history_file
>>> import readline.write_history_file as whf 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline.write_history_file'; 'readline' is not a package

# However, readline itself imports
>>> import readline
>>> readline.get_history_item(2)
'version'
```

`readline` does appear to be explicitly part of the Cygwin repository, so I didn't try `pip install readline`:

- Search Cygwin packages for [`readline`](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=readline&arch=x86_64) (followed by browser search for the string `python`)
- The one [result](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fpython38%2Fpython38-3.8.10-1&grep=readline) that appears to be most relevant shows `dll`,`py`, and `pyc` files with `readline[s]` in the file name, but I'm not sure what that says about the form taken by the `readline` *module* itself.  I welcome clarifications/explanations about this.

In fact, I'm reluctant to try installing anything outside of the Cygwin package manager using `pip` for fear of creating inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through [this module](https://bugs.python.org/file31096/history.py), I found out [`readline.write_history_file(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#readline.write_history_file) may be what you are searching for:

> Save the history list to a readline history file, overwriting any existing file.
> The default filename is `~/.history`
> First thing in the interactive interpreter, do

```py
import readline.write_history_file as whf # write history file
```

Then you can do `whf()` or `whf("path/to/.historyfile")`, and your python history gets saved to disk immediately.

EDIT:

> I'm not sure how often it is updated

It is only updated when you exit the interpreter. If you kill it, the history won't get saved, and `Ctrl+Z` just causes the interpreter to be suspended. If you then unsuspend it (by executing `fg` or `bg`, for example) and exit it normally, the history file will get written.

Comment: Thanks, Programmer.  I'm going to have to wait until I'm in a good position to update my host environment (Cygwin).  That's the Python that I use.  It doesn't currently recognize `import readline.write_history_file as whf # write history file`: `'readline' is not a package`.

Comment: @user36800 ah, I didn't know you were using Windows. `readline` is not supported on Windows. Try using `pyreadline` (`pip install pyreadline`); I read that's the replacement on Windows.

Comment: Cygwin provides a unix-like layer, including `readline`.  I use `readline` with bash, octave, and Python sans GUI.  I have yet to search for the Python package for `readline` on Cygwin, but I'm somewhat sure that it would be there.

Comment: @user36800 okay, maybe `pip install readline` could work ?

Comment: It could.  My luck with `pip install` has been pretty poor.  Something I haven't worked out in having system wide Python installed via Cygwin and user-specific packages installed under the user's own folder tree.  I may still have to do that, however, even after a Cygwin install.